# script for entering data in next empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Slowly working my way through understanding javaScript and variations like GAS, but a total beginner.

I have a script which upon execution copies a formula as values, and pastes it to another cell. A sort of archiving feature.

```
function csArchive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origin = ss.getRange('sheet1!D17');
  origin.copyTo(ss.getRange('sheet1!Z2'), {contentsOnly: true});
```

In other words, the script does:
1. copy from active sheet and the range specified.
2. Paste to the range specified (z2).
what is missing from there is - check if z2 is empty and if it's not, go down until you find an empty cell then paste the value.

I believe my salvation is with `.getLastRow()` but for the life of me I cannot get it to work properly. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The next empty cell where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last Row in Column Z in activeSheet

```
function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  //var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var col = col || 26;
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

An example of how to use this:

```
function csArchive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var origin = sh.getRange('sheet1!D17');
  origin.copyTo(sh.getRange(getColumnHeight(26)+1,26), {contentsOnly: true});
  //origin.copyTo(sh.getRange(getColumnHeight()+1,26), {contentsOnly: true});//You can also do it this way since I defaulted col parameter to 26
}
```

Are you saying that you have something like this:

[image]

Assuming that you won't let that range fill up:

```
function getNextEmptyCell(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,26,54,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length + 1;
}

function csArchive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var origin = sh.getRange('sheet1!D17');
  origin.copyTo(sh.getRange(getNextEmptyCell(),26), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: That works. Small caveat - I wanted the next available (empty) cell to be used, as I have a sum function after 55 cells.
I have 3 options:
1. move the sum formula at the top.

2. Move the formula somewhere else.

3. Change the code.  If you have suggestions about #3 I'm all ears. In any case thank you for your help!

Comment: Refer to my answer with the image and please answer the question.

Comment: Sorry. I changed the image several times.

Comment: If that's the case, I  would move it to the top or at least somewhere out of that column.  It could be done but you will have to tell me where the additional stuff is and what to do if it all gets filled up.  So for simplicity I would just move it.

Comment: Yes your image is accurate. Z1 has a title, Z2-55 are blank and to be used by the script, z56 has a formula. Your code ignores any empty cells between say... z5 and z56 and writes below the sum formula - (z57 for me, z18 in your image).

Comment: My comment question was if there's a simple way of the script finding the First Available Cell, instead of First Cell after the Last with Data. Otherwise as I said I will just move the formula away from Col Z.

Comment: What would you do when that range fills up?

Comment: Each cell is a week in a year therefore it won't come to that.

Comment: Okay, then my last edit should do it.  I modified the function and renamed it so look closely at what you have.

Comment: I changed the `getNextEmptyCell()` function by changing the number of rows in the getRange().

Comment: Thank you again Cooper, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!